# Could not find gem 'rubytree (~> 0.5.2) ruby' while installing ChiliProject on Debian

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, chiliproject

I am trying to install chiliproject on a server, following the -well done- documentation I am hitting this error

```
Could not find gem 'rubytree (~> 0.5.2) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I did a gem install rubytree

I get this message

```
========================================================================

 Thank you for installing rubytree.

              WARNING: SIGNIFICANT API CHANGE in 0.8.0 !
              ------------------------------------------

 Please note that as of 0.8.0 the CamelCase method names are DEPRECATED.

 The new method names follow the ruby_convention (separated by '_').

 The old CamelCase methods still work (a warning will be displayed),
 but may go away in the future.

 Details of the API changes are documented in the API-CHANGES file.

========================================================================
Successfully installed rubytree-0.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rubytree-0.8.1...
file 'COPYING,API-CHANGES' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rubytree-0.8.1...
file 'COPYING,API-CHANGES' not found
```

That is saying the installation was succesful. So why do I get the error ?
If the error is from the API change how can I request version 0.5.2 of the rubytree gem ?

When I do a `gem list --local | grep 'rubytree'`
I have this output `rubytree (0.8.1)`

So why is the system saying could not find gem 'rubytree' ?

thank you for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of rails you are using (and it sounds like you are using a relatively newer one, if it's prompting you for your Gemfile), then you need to use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage your gems.

Try editing your Gemfile, adding a new line that reads:

```
gem "rubytree", "< 0.6"
```

Then open up a console, and type this command

```
bundle install
```

This should fix your problems, but if you still get errors when running a command, then try typing `bundle exec` prior to the command (i.e. `rails server` becomes `bundle exec rails server`).

Comment: ChiliProject already uses bundler and specifies `rubytree ~> 0.5.2`. And we are rather insistent on that currently...

Comment: Well if you hadn't noticed, the highest version of rubytree < 0.6 is 0.5.3.  Just saying.  Your line does exactly the same thing as mine unless the creators of rubytree suddenly decide to release version 0.5.8 or something.

Comment: Yes, but given that your proposed edit doesn't do anything what we don't already have. Sorry if that sounded a bit rude...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we require `rubytree` exactly in version 0.5.2 or 0.5.3, as specified in our `Gemfile`, the 0.8.1. version you installed by hand will not suffice that requirement, which is exactly what the error message states.

What seems a bit odd is the literal `ruby` in the error message. Could you please make sure that you have the exact unchanged `Gemfile` from the source on your system? Also, could you please remove any user-installed plugins and try again? Also, which ruby (type and version) on which operating system are you using?

Comment: I neved opened the Gemfile to edit it myself.For the ruby version, ruby -v output is this ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux] for the OS is Debian 6.0. AI have no plugin installed. I took the doc from the beginning and was following it until I reached there. I hadn't ruby previous installed on this server.